# find values that occurs the least in 2 columns file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I've a dynamically generated txt file of this structure -> Code[space]Link

This is a simple

```
15210 https://test1.com
4 https://test2.com
1020 https://testc.com
152 https://testz.com
152 https://test5.com
10 https://test54.com
152 https://testx.com
10 https://testds.com
15210 https://testmp.com
```

It can get bigger upto 100 million line

I want to show only all the links on the file only if the same Code isn't repeated more or equal 3 times for example.

in this situation the output will be

```
https://test1.com
https://test2.com
https://testc.com
https://test54.com
https://testds.com
https://testmp.com
```

all the links in front of 152 code won't show in output 'cause 152 is repeated >= 3 times. the same if any other Code value is repeated >=3 times.

Just, I want the number of this condition that was 3 in above example to be user input in the command.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a two pass solution like so:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{cnt[$1]++; next} cnt[$1]<3{print $2}' file file
```

Prints:

```
https://test1.com
https://test2.com
https://testc.com
https://test54.com
https://testds.com
https://testmp.com
```

Or, if you have a number of elements defined in `$1` that you can't hold them in memory, you could sort first and then separate the blocks then only print the `$2` in the lines in a block with less than 3 lines:

```
sort -n file | awk '
    $1==last || FNR==1{print; last=$1; next}
    {last=$1; print ""; print}
' | awk '
    BEGIN { RS = "" ; FS = "\n" }
    NF<3{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i, a, " ")
        print a[2]
        }
    }
'
```

This will be slower and the order in the original file will be lost.

Comment: thank you so much, both solutions work. special thanks for the first one since it's quick hacky one!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single pass through the sorted output with `awk` as well. For example you can do:

```bash
sort -n yourfile |
awk '
  FNR == 1 {
    code = $1
    lasturl[$2] = 1
    n = 1
    next
  }
  $1 == code {
    n++
    lasturl[$2] = 1
    next
  } 
  {
    if (n < 3) {
      for (i in lasturl)
        print i
    }
    code = $1
    delete lasturl
    lasturl[$2] = 1
    n = 1
  }
  END { if (n < 3) for (i in lasturl) print i }
'
```

(largest array is simply the largest number of duplicate codes (e.g. 3-elements for your three `152` codes) instead of one-element for each code)

**Example Use/Output**

The `sort -n` will change the order of your output, but given input in `yourfile` above you would have:

```
https://test2.com
https://testds.com
https://test54.com
https://testc.com
https://testmp.com
https://test1.com
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Glad it helps. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk and sort:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort -k1,1 "${@:--}" |
awk -v max=3 '
    $1 != prev {
        if ( cnt < max  ) {
            printf "%s", codes
        }
        prev  = $1
        cnt   = 0
        codes = ""
    }
    {
        cnt++
        codes = codes $2 ORS
    }
    END {
        if ( cnt < max ) {
            printf "%s", codes
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
https://test54.com
https://testds.com
https://testc.com
https://test1.com
https://testmp.com
https://test2.com
```